# SSH connect to FreeBSD9 suddenly started to freeze randomly

Tags: networking, ssh, freebsd

I have a KVM FreeBSD 9.2 box for a long time. 5 days ago I had a 2h ssh incoming session on this box with no freezes. 
No system/soft updates or significant system changes were made.

Today I can't normally connect to the box: It hangs on random connect stage or a few seconds after successful connect.

I tried all the classic solutions like enabling the KeepAlive on server, disabling DNS, and disabling the GSSAPIAuthentication. Deleted all ipfw deny and nat records to be sure. Disabled 3proxy and openvpn service, added google DNS to /etc/resolv.conf at server.
I tried to connect with key or password - no difference between these methods.

Enabling keepalive at server makes me see these lines even after freeze of connection:

```
debug1: client_input_channel_req: channel 0 rtype keepalive@openssh.com reply 1
```

Once `ssh -vvv` hung here:

```
debug1: Roaming not allowed by server
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent
```

Next time it connects and I can type a symbol or few until freeze.
On server-side last line after `/usr/sbin/sshd -d` is

```
Setting controlling tty using tiocsctty
```

I have a VNC connectivity to the box so I could tune server-part.
No useful information is `messages`

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Would you suspect any file system corruption and do you have a snapshot you could try to restore? Things don't break without a reason. Either there was something new installed either on the host or guest system or something broke. Maybe you could try to reinstall or upgrade to 10.3, since upgrading to a new version would recreate most system files?

Answer (score 0):

It was all my network provider's fault. I revealed unusually big loss rate while using mtr to any host outside my local network. They did some diagnostics (disable/enable my adsl port etc) and ssh connectivity to my box became good as before.

Sorry for bothering you.